# I don't know how transfer my variable in android

Tags: android, url, android-intent

so sorry for trouble.
I want to make a search Google. First time i have create edittext and button. In button it is create un link for access in browser.

I had a errror when add text in link. The variable **mEdit** does not match the written
Help me, please.

```
button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    mEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    mEdit.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());


    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String url = "https://www.google.com/search?q="+mEdit;
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

Comment: You don't have enough code here.  Please post your html as well.  See [mcve]

Comment: i have added, all code... I want to make search bar google

Comment: use `mEdit.getText().toString()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call

```
String url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + mEdit.getText().toString();
```

to get the text inside the edittext